# Throttle speed at which a servlet accepts an HTTP Post Body under Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-upload, upload

I have a servlet that accepts large (up to 4GB) binary file uploads. The submitted file is transmitted as the body of an HTTP POST.

The servlet has to perform some time-consuming processing as it receives the file, and it has to finish doing that before sending the response. As a result, it can appear to a fast client that the server has hung because the client can be waiting for a minute or two after sending the the last few bytes before getting the response.

Is there a way either within Tomcat or within the servlet API to throttle back the speed at which the server accepts the file? I would like it to appear to the client that the server is accepting the file at (for example) 10MB/second rather than it accepting the file at 50MB/second and then taking a few minutes after receiving the body to return a response.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a web filter and pass the request within a wrapper that uses a throttled input stream. Upload speed depends on the input buffers and regular frameworks do not throttle on read. You can find a throttling InputStream at https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/blob/master/src/test/java/org/littleshoot/proxy/ThrottledInputStream.java

Comment: Thanks, @mp911de. That ThrottledInputStream throttles the reader, but what I want to do is throttle it from the client's perspective. I am already reading the ServletInputStream much more slowly than it is filling up.

Comment: Then the rest of the content is being buffered at the network layer and there is little you can do about that. To the client it will look like things are hung while the servlet continues to read the buffered data. Maybe change the design and send a "processing..." response to the client immediately followed by the actual response once processing is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm extending on the comment of Mark Thomas here because I feel that this is worth being an answer (or *the* answer), rather than a comment. Mark, let me know if you want to convert the comment yourself and I'll happily delete mine.

John, you're trying to solve your problem in a way that imposes severe limitations: What's the bandwidth that you want to throttle to? What happens when the server is upgraded to a beefier CPU and can process more quickly? What if multiple uploads happen at the same time?

You probably want to have an upload of 4G in as quick a time as possible - imagine the connection going down in the middle - in a web application this typically means you'll have to restart the upload from the beginning. Thus you should decouple your processing from the upload procedure as much as possible.

You also don't mention the file format that gets uploaded: If it happens to be a zip file, note that the server can't do anything with the file until it's fully transmitted, as zip files have the directory of contents at their end. (this might be old knowledge, but at least the old spec had it this way. Someone correct me if this changed)

So: The proper way: Accept the file for processing, signal that you received it and are processing. If you like: Implement Ajax updates once you're done. In the simplest case: "click here to see if processing finished" or frequently reload the page. Anything works and everything is better than throttling throughput on this layer.